# how to use the jquery autocomplete label in my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

how to use the jquery autocomplete label in my web application . i want to use the jquery autocomplete lebel . i want the result like New york, USA

```
$('#countryname_1').autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
           name_startsWith: request.term,
           type: 'country_table',
           row_num : 1
        },
         success: function( data ) {

            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                    var len=code.length;
                    var co= code[0];

                return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data : item

                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
autoFocus: true,            
minLength: 0,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|").length; 
    var dat = ui.item.data.split("|");  
    //alert(dat);                   
    //$('#country_no_1').val(names[1]);

}
```

});

Comment: So what's your specific question?

Comment: my question is on every search autocomplete shoulds  show like new york,USA . right now it shows like New york only . so how do i change the label